# Delete file after script terminated

Tags: bash, shell, command, abort

I was asking myself if it is possible that when I terminate a bash script with crtl+c, the script would execute a last command before aborting, like delete a file which was created by that script?

Answer (score 3):

You can trap the pseudo-signal `EXIT` to execute something before exiting for any reason:

```
trap 'rm myfile' EXIT
```

or trap `INT` to excecute a command on before exiting due to Control-C:

```
trap 'rm myfile' INT
```

Comment: A trap can call a function, which can ben handy to handle all cleanup operations together.

Comment: The ERR trap can be used to handle errors.  It it triggered on non-zero return codes (see Bash documentation if interested, as there are special cases).

Answer (score 0):

You want ctrl-c trapping for post script cleanup.

https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

You can first trap ctrl+c by :

`trap ctrl_c INT`

This line will call a function `ctrl_c` after pressing ctrl+c(stopping the execution of the script).
Then make a function `ctrl_c` and delete the files which you want to delete inside that function like this:

```
function ctrl_c(){
     rm -rf ~/PATH-OF-THE-FILE-TO-DELETE
}
```